# grep failing in gitlab CI

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

I am trying to finalyze a script in Gitlab CI but struggling with some syntax error

```
  script: |        
          echo "running jenkins job from user $EMAIL using following settings - $BRANCH /  $TAGS in $ENV enviroment" 
          
          lastbuildNumber=$(curl -s --user ${EMAIL}:${TOKEN} "$JENKINS_URL/$ENV-SmokeTests-UIOnly/lastBuild/api/json"  | jq ".number")

          echo "last build was number ${lastbuildNumber}"
          currentBuild=$((lastbuildNumber + 1 ))  
          
          echo "current build is ${currentBuild}"

          echo "view cucumber report here"
          baseurl="$JENKINS_URL/${ENV}-SmokeTests-UIOnly"
          echo $baseurl
          
          curl -s --user $EMAIL:$TOKEN $JENKINS_URL/$ENV-SmokeTests-UIOnly/ --output cucumber.txt


          cucumber_endpoint=$(cat cucumber.txt | grep -o -m 1 "[a-zA-Z.-]*/cucumber-html-reports_[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*")

          full_cucumber=$baseurl$cucumber_endpoint

          echo $full_cucumber
```

The script works fine on my local terminal, but fails in the CI when running

```
cucumber_endpoint=$(cat cucumber.txt | grep -o -m 1 "[a-zA-Z.-]*/cucumber-html-reports_[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*")
```

is for sure something related to quotes but cannot work out what the issue is.

---

update:

I changed to:

```
after_script:
    - |
        echo "view cucumber report here"
        baseurl="$JENKINS_URL/job/${ENV}-SmokeTests-UIOnly"

        curl -s --user "$EMAIL":"$TOKEN" $JENKINS_URL/"$ENV"-SmokeTests-UIOnly/ --output cucumber.txt
        cat cucumber.txt 
        
        cucumber_endpoint=$(cat cucumber.txt | grep -o -m 1 '[a-zA-Z.-]*/cucumber-html-reports_[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*')
        full_cucumber="${baseurl}${cucumber_endpoint}"
        echo "${full_cucumber}"
```

and I have run the script through 'shellcheck.net'

it's the grep that is not working but is not returning anyerror now.

the result of the `cat` command are correct, as on my local machine.

---

proving is not an issue with `set -e`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
        echo "view cucumber report here"
        baseurl="https://example"

        cucumber_endpoint=$(curl -s --user "$EMAIL":"$TOKEN" ${JENKINS_URL}/"$ENV"-SmokeTests-UIOnly/ | grep -o -m 1 '[a-zA-Z.-]*/cucumber-html-reports_[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*')
        # cat cucumber.txt 
        
        # cucumber_endpoint=$(cucumber.txt | grep -o -m 1 '[a-zA-Z.-]*/cucumber-html-reports_[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*')
        full_cucumber="${cucumber_endpoint}"
        echo "${baseurl}${full_cucumber}"
```

which gets what I want:

```
 ➜ ./cucumber.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         [16/02/23|11:39:59|]
view cucumber report here
https://example/cucumber-html-reports_fb3a3468-c298-3fb5-ad9a-dacbc0323763/overview-features.html
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the script runs with `set -e` and your problem is unrelated to quoting. If you find otherwise, please [edit] your question to clarify, and ping me to get it reopened. If there really is a syntax error, what is the precise error message?

Comment: However, your script contains various quoting errors etc; probably run it through https://shellcheck.net/

Comment: I can't see any indication that my guess is incorrect. What's in the `cat` output? (Notice also that the `cat` to `grep` is [useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).)

Comment: I need to get and endpoint of an url that matches the regex in my grep call. the cat output is just a html file. and I was just decomposing the commands to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently gitlab ci did not like the `-m 1` option in the grep call

so changed to

```
cucumber_endpoint=$(curl -s --user "$EMAIL":"$TOKEN" ${JENKINS_URL}/"$ENV"-SmokeTests-UIOnly/ | grep -o '[a-zA-Z.-]*/cucumber-html-reports_[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*'| sort -u)
```

Comment: `sort -u` is a weird attempt to fix it; perhaps `head -n 1` would be better? Or `tail -n 1`?